# notification dots missing - Samsung S22

Tags: samsung, notifications, home-screen-shortcuts

An S22 of my friend's has changed appearance overnight and now the app notification dots are not displaying on the home page icons, but the icons at the top of the screen are showing, which they apparently were not before.  How can I re-enable the dots and hide the top-of-screen icons?

[image]

Comment: "*has changed appearance overnight*" was this by any chance [Easy Mode](https://www.samsung.com/au/support/mobile-devices/using-easy-mode/)? Otherwise, are they using a 3rd-party home screen/launcher app?

Comment: My friend is non-technical and we were drinking last night and messing with the phone. While trying to screen share to the TV someone probably touched something and switched it over. This is apparently "my fault" and so I am tasked with fixing it.  I will look at easy mode.

Comment: I'm not sure about "top-of-screen icons" though, and it might probably help if we can get a screenshot of it...

Comment: I don't know the technical term.  Where your battery icon and signal strength and everything is.  I get the impression she normally doesn't see new text message icons up there for example usually just the dot on the bigger icon in the main part of the screen.

Comment: Ah, the notification/status bar. By default, notifications will show icons on the notification bar, while notification dots/badges can be toggled from the home screen settings; e.g. by long-pressing on an empty space of the home screen. However, there are some other settings related to the visibility of notifications, like Notifications themselves and even maybe Do Not Disturb.

Comment: ok so I added an image - you can see there are no dots on the snapchat icon for example  but there's a notification in the notification bar.  According to her she did not see the icon in the bar before for that, but there would be a dot.  Are you saying both of those things are accomplished by long-pressing the home screen and selecting some option?  this is something we could have fat fingered while handing it back and forth last night I think.

Comment: @AndrewT. go ahead and create that comment as an answer because that ultimately worked - I will mark it as accepted.  It was a little more involved to get the dots back than I would have thought so my guess about "fat-fingering" it is probably not accurate.  But fixed is fixed and I will call it a win for now.

Comment: Glad to hear it's fixed. Also, feel free to self-answer it too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenter Andrew T. gave me an answer.

Ultimately, long-pressing the background of the home-screen took me to the edit screen for the page, and there was a button in there to adjust the settings.  Within that menu was a switch to enable the notification badges for the different app icons.  I believe the notification icons were still present in the notification bar at the top of the screen, but we determined that was a success.